# Does this code produce 2 NSTimers instead of 1?

Tags: xcode, nstimer, nsoperationqueue

I am creating a work queue to perform tasks in the background. The code is below. The problem is that selector called by the timer is called twice every period, by 2 different timers.

The queue (UpdateController) is created in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of the AppDelegate:

```
...
[self setUpdateController:[[FFUpdateController alloc] initWithRootDetailViewController:rdvc]];
[[self updateController] start];
...
```

Here’s the UpdateController initializer

```
- (id) initWithRootDetailViewController:(FFRootDetailViewController*)rdvc
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _rootDetailViewController = rdvc;
        _updateQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Here’s UpdateController start

```
- (void) start
{
    //sweep once a minute for updates
    [self setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0 target:self selector:@selector(sweepForUpdates:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]]; 
}
```

Here is sweepForUpdates, the selector called by the timer:

```
- (void) sweepForUpdates:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    FormHeader* fh;
    NSInvocationOperation* op;
    NSInteger sectionIdx = [[self dataController] sectionIndexForFormTypeWithTitle:SFTShares];
    NSInteger headerCount = [[self dataController] numberOfRowsInSection:sectionIdx];
    NSArray* changed;
    NSMutableDictionary* params;

    NSLog(@"Notice - sweepForUpdates(1) called:");
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < headerCount; i++)
    {
        fh = [[self dataController] formHeaderAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:sectionIdx]];
        changed = [[self dataController] formDatasModifiedSince:[fh modifiedAt] ForFormHeader:fh];

        if ([changed count])
        {
            NSLog(@"Error - sweepForUpdates(2) update: changes to update found");
            params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [params setObject:fh forKey:@"formHeader"];
            [params setObject:[self rootDetailViewController] forKey:@"rootDetailViewController"];

            op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:[FFParseController sharedInstance] selector:@selector(updateRemoteForm:) object:params];

            if ([[[self updateQueue] operations] count])
            {
                [op addDependency:[[[self updateQueue] operations] lastObject]];
            }
            [[self updateQueue] addOperation:op];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error - sweepForUpdates(3) save: no changes found");
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Notice - sweepForUpdates(4) done:");
}
```

In this case there are 2 objects to examine for updates. Here is the console output for 1 sweep:

```
2015-02-16 09:22:28.569 formogen[683:806645] Notice - sweepForUpdates(1) called:
2015-02-16 09:22:28.580 formogen[683:806645] Error - sweepForUpdates(3) save: no changes found
2015-02-16 09:22:28.583 formogen[683:806645] Error - sweepForUpdates(3) save: no changes found
2015-02-16 09:22:28.584 formogen[683:806645] Notice - sweepForUpdates(4) done:
2015-02-16 09:22:29.249 formogen[683:806645] Notice - sweepForUpdates(1) called:
2015-02-16 09:22:29.254 formogen[683:806645] Error - sweepForUpdates(3) save: no changes found
2015-02-16 09:22:29.256 formogen[683:806645] Error - sweepForUpdates(3) save: no changes found
2015-02-16 09:22:29.256 formogen[683:806645] Notice - sweepForUpdates(4) done:
```

Neither object has updates, which is correct. But I do not understand why the selector is called twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add logging to `start`. You probably call it more than once.

Note that `UpdateController` can never deallocate, because the timer is retaining it. That may be ok, but keep that in mind if you believe you're deallocating it (and its timer).

Comment: You are right. Start is called twice. Is there something that made you see that?

Comment: It schedules a timer. You had two timers. Ergo, you probably call it twice. It's a pretty common bug.

Comment: 80% of the time when I say right away "you probably messed this up," it's because I've messed that up at least a dozen times before.